# Openapi-generator File names are long

Tags: typescript, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm running **openapi-generator-cli**

With

`docker run --rm -v "${PWD}:/local" openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate -i local/open-api-spec.json -g typescript-fetch -o /local/out/Typescript`

My **open-api-spec.json** file has a definitions section with file name

E.g.

`Abc.Def.MyDto`

When **openapi-generator-cli** runs the Dto's name is AbcDefMyDto.
Some of them are really long and unsightly to read.

How do I tell **open-api-generator** to make it look like **MyDto**?